# Django TemplateDoesNotExist at /home/

Tags: python, django

directory structure of dummy project

```
/dummy

   /dummy

            urls.py
            views.py
            setting.py
            _init_
            wsgi.py
    /template
            home.html
```

**settings.py**

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    "D:/Data/Codes/Django_Code/dummy/template"
    )
```

**views.py**

```
from  django.shortcuts import render_to_response

from  django.template import RequestContext

def home_view(request):
    render_to_response(request, 'home.html')
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
    
from dummy.views import home_view
    
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^home/$', home_view),
    )
```

scratching my head over TemplateDoesNotExist Although have specified template directory in setting.py under TEMPLATE_DIRS

Error Trace
Template-loader postmortem

```
Django tried loading these templates, in this order:
Using loader django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader:
D:\Data\Codes\Django_Code\dummy\template\<WSGIRequest
path:\home\,
GET:<QueryDict: {}>,
POST:<QueryDict: {}>,
COOKIES:{'csrftoken': 'CNnHomGRMMJmik75Pi2rclMVdPjO36t9'},
META:{'ALLUSERSPROFILE': 'C:\ProgramData',
 'APPDATA': 'C:\Users\nitin\AppData\Roaming',
 'CLASSPATH': '.;D:\data\Codes;C:\Users\nitin\Downloads\javapostmark\apache-mime4j-0.6.jar;C:\Users\nitin\Downloads\javapostmark\commons-codec-1.3.jar;C:\Users\nitin\Downloads\javapostmark\commons-logging-1.1.1.jar;C:\Users\nitin\Downloads\javapostmark\gson-1.4.jar;C:\Users\nitin\Downloads\javapostmark\httpclient-4.0.1.jar;C:\Users\nitin\Downloads\javapostmark\httpcore-4.0.1.jar;C:\Users\nitin\Downloads\javapostmark\httpmime-4.0.1.jar;C:\Users\nitin\Downloads\javapostmark\joda-time-1.6.jar;',
 'COMMONPROGRAMFILES': 'C:\Program Files\Common Files',
 'COMMONPROGRAMFILES(X86)': 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files',
 'COMMONPROGRAMW6432': 'C:\Program Files\Common Files',
 'COMPUTERNAME': 'NITIN-PC',
 'COMSPEC': 'C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe',
 'CONTENT_LENGTH': '',
 'CONTENT_TYPE': 'text\plain',
 'CSRF_COOKIE': 'CNnHomGRMMJmik75Pi2rclMVdPjO36t9',
 'DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE': 'dummy.settings',
 'FP_NO_HOST_CHECK': 'NO',
 'GATEWAY_INTERFACE': 'CGI\1.1',
 'HOMEDRIVE': 'C:',
 'HOMEPATH': '\Users\nitin',
 'HTTP_ACCEPT': 'text\html,application\xhtml+xml,application\xml;q=0.9,*\*;q=0.8',
 'HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',
 'HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING': 'gzip,deflate,sdch',
 'HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
 'HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL': 'max-age=0',
 'HTTP_CONNECTION': 'keep-alive',
 'HTTP_COOKIE': 'csrftoken=CNnHomGRMMJmik75Pi2rclMVdPjO36t9',
 'HTTP_HOST': '127.0.0.1:8000',
 'HTTP_USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla\5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit\537.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome\22.0.1229.94 Safari\537.4',
 'JAVA_HOME': 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_05;',
 'LOCALAPPDATA': 'C:\Users\nitin\AppData\Local',
 'LOGONSERVER': '\NITIN-PC',
 'NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS': '2',
 'OS': 'Windows_NT',
 'PATH': 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\bin;C:\Python27;C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts',
 'PATHEXT': '.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC',
 'PATH_INFO': u'\home\',
 'PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE': 'AMD64',
 'PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER': 'Intel64 Family 6 Model 23 Stepping 10, GenuineIntel',
 'PROCESSOR_LEVEL': '6',
 'PROCESSOR_REVISION': '170a',
 'PROGRAMDATA': 'C:\ProgramData',
 'PROGRAMFILES': 'C:\Program Files',
 'PROGRAMFILES(X86)': 'C:\Program Files (x86)',
 'PROGRAMW6432': 'C:\Program Files',
 'PROMPT': '$P$G',
 'PSMODULEPATH': 'C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\',
 'PUBLIC': 'C:\Users\Public',
 'QUERY_STRING': '',
 'REMOTE_ADDR': '127.0.0.1',
 'REMOTE_HOST': '',
 'REQUEST_METHOD': 'GET',
 'RUN_MAIN': 'true',
 'SCRIPT_NAME': u'',
 'SERVER_NAME': 'nitin-PC',
 'SERVER_PORT': '8000',
 'SERVER_PROTOCOL': 'HTTP\1.1',
 'SERVER_SOFTWARE': 'WSGIServer\0.1 Python\2.7.3',
 'SESSIONNAME': 'Console',
 'SYSTEMDRIVE': 'C:',
 'SYSTEMROOT': 'C:\Windows',
 'TEMP': 'C:\Users\nitin\AppData\Local\Temp',
 'TMP': 'C:\Users\nitin\AppData\Local\Temp',
 'USERDOMAIN': 'nitin-PC',
 'USERNAME': 'nitin',
 'USERPROFILE': 'C:\Users\nitin',
 'WINDIR': 'C:\Windows',
 'wsgi.errors': <open file '<stderr>', mode 'w' at 0x0000000001D761E0>,
 'wsgi.file_wrapper': <class wsgiref.util.FileWrapper at 0x0000000002E5D5E8>,
 'wsgi.input': <socket._fileobject object at 0x000000000327F138>,
 'wsgi.multiprocess': False,
 'wsgi.multithread': True,
 'wsgi.run_once': False,
 'wsgi.url_scheme': 'http',
 'wsgi.version': (1, 0)}> (File does not exist)
Using loader django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader:
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\templates\<WSGIRequest
path:\home\,
GET:<QueryDict: {}>,
POST:<QueryDict: {}>,
COOKIES:{'csrftoken': 'CNnHomGRMMJmik75Pi2rclMVdPjO36t9'},
META:{'ALLUSERSPROFILE': 'C:\ProgramData',
 'APPDATA': 'C:\Users\nitin\AppData\Roaming',
 'CLASSPATH': '.;D:\data\Codes;C:\Users\nitin\Downloads\javapostmark\apache-mime4j-0.6.jar;C:\Users\nitin\Downloads\javapostmark\commons-codec-1.3.jar;C:\Users\nitin\Downloads\javapostmark\commons-logging-1.1.1.jar;C:\Users\nitin\Downloads\javapostmark\gson-1.4.jar;C:\Users\nitin\Downloads\javapostmark\httpclient-4.0.1.jar;C:\Users\nitin\Downloads\javapostmark\httpcore-4.0.1.jar;C:\Users\nitin\Downloads\javapostmark\httpmime-4.0.1.jar;C:\Users\nitin\Downloads\javapostmark\joda-time-1.6.jar;',
 'COMMONPROGRAMFILES': 'C:\Program Files\Common Files',
 'COMMONPROGRAMFILES(X86)': 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files',
 'COMMONPROGRAMW6432': 'C:\Program Files\Common Files',
 'COMPUTERNAME': 'NITIN-PC',
 'COMSPEC': 'C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe',
 'CONTENT_LENGTH': '',
 'CONTENT_TYPE': 'text\plain',
 'CSRF_COOKIE': 'CNnHomGRMMJmik75Pi2rclMVdPjO36t9',
 'DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE': 'dummy.settings',
 'FP_NO_HOST_CHECK': 'NO',
 'GATEWAY_INTERFACE': 'CGI\1.1',
 'HOMEDRIVE': 'C:',
 'HOMEPATH': '\Users\nitin',
 'HTTP_ACCEPT': 'text\html,application\xhtml+xml,application\xml;q=0.9,*\*;q=0.8',
 'HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',
 'HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING': 'gzip,deflate,sdch',
 'HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
 'HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL': 'max-age=0',
 'HTTP_CONNECTION': 'keep-alive',
 'HTTP_COOKIE': 'csrftoken=CNnHomGRMMJmik75Pi2rclMVdPjO36t9',
 'HTTP_HOST': '127.0.0.1:8000',
 'HTTP_USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla\5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit\537.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome\22.0.1229.94 Safari\537.4',
 'JAVA_HOME': 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_05;',
 'LOCALAPPDATA': 'C:\Users\nitin\AppData\Local',
 'LOGONSERVER': '\NITIN-PC',
 'NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS': '2',
 'OS': 'Windows_NT',
 'PATH': 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\bin;C:\Python27;C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts',
 'PATHEXT': '.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC',
 'PATH_INFO': u'\home\',
 'PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE': 'AMD64',
 'PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER': 'Intel64 Family 6 Model 23 Stepping 10, GenuineIntel',
 'PROCESSOR_LEVEL': '6',
 'PROCESSOR_REVISION': '170a',
 'PROGRAMDATA': 'C:\ProgramData',
 'PROGRAMFILES': 'C:\Program Files',
 'PROGRAMFILES(X86)': 'C:\Program Files (x86)',
 'PROGRAMW6432': 'C:\Program Files',
 'PROMPT': '$P$G',
 'PSMODULEPATH': 'C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\',
 'PUBLIC': 'C:\Users\Public',
 'QUERY_STRING': '',
 'REMOTE_ADDR': '127.0.0.1',
 'REMOTE_HOST': '',
 'REQUEST_METHOD': 'GET',
 'RUN_MAIN': 'true',
 'SCRIPT_NAME': u'',
 'SERVER_NAME': 'nitin-PC',
 'SERVER_PORT': '8000',
 'SERVER_PROTOCOL': 'HTTP\1.1',
 'SERVER_SOFTWARE': 'WSGIServer\0.1 Python\2.7.3',
 'SESSIONNAME': 'Console',
 'SYSTEMDRIVE': 'C:',
 'SYSTEMROOT': 'C:\Windows',
 'TEMP': 'C:\Users\nitin\AppData\Local\Temp',
 'TMP': 'C:\Users\nitin\AppData\Local\Temp',
 'USERDOMAIN': 'nitin-PC',
 'USERNAME': 'nitin',
 'USERPROFILE': 'C:\Users\nitin',
 'WINDIR': 'C:\Windows',
 'wsgi.errors': <open file '<stderr>', mode 'w' at 0x0000000001D761E0>,
 'wsgi.file_wrapper': <class wsgiref.util.FileWrapper at 0x0000000002E5D5E8>,
 'wsgi.input': <socket._fileobject object at 0x000000000327F138>,
 'wsgi.multiprocess': False,
 'wsgi.multithread': True,
 'wsgi.run_once': False,
 'wsgi.url_scheme': 'http',
 'wsgi.version': (1, 0)}> (File does not exist)
```

Comment: Try to remove the trailing slash in render_to_response(request, 'home.html/') <--- remove slash

Comment: tried render_to_response(request, 'home.html') didn't work

Comment: Try,  TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    "D:/Data/Codes/Django_Code/dummy/template/"
    )

Comment: Not sure if it is a typo but TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    "D:/Data/Codes/Django_Code/dummy/template"
    } <--- change to closing parenthesis

Comment: different template directories are separated by comma

Comment: yes but you have a } instead of a ) in the example above and it should end with a comma. Like this: TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    "D:/Data/Codes/Django_Code/dummy/template",
    )

Comment: it was a typing mistake. my bad

Comment: Do you have the comma in place too?  "D:/Data/Codes/Django_Code/dummy/template", <-- comma here

Comment: Please paste the full TemplateDoesNotExist stacktrace and debug info: it should **tell you what directories it has tryied !!**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. **[Never hardcode absolute paths](http://blog.yourlabs.org/post/27477234167/never-hardcode-absolute-paths)**.
2. Your `TEMPLATE_DIRS` is not an iterable, the dir should be between `[]`
3. In case of problems, just run `manage.py shell` and `from django.conf import settings; print settings.TEMPLATE_DIRS[0]`, this will show you the path used by django.
4. Another way to see if django should find your template in `manage.py shell` is `from django.template import loader; print loader.get_template('home.html')`. Django should tell you what template directories it tries when it fails. That's important.

Comment: printing exactly : D:/Data/Codes/Django_Code/dummy/template

Comment: Very well, in a cmd do `D:` then `cd Data/Codes/Django_Code/dummy/template` then `dir`. You should see your template. If you don't, then it's normal that django doesn't see it. Also, I added a tip to the answer.

Comment: What about hint #4 ? Also, did you replace your absolute paths already ? Else it will just break when you try to deploy your project on a server ...

Comment: try in `manage.py shell`: `import os.path; print os.path.exists('D:\Data\Codes\Django_Code\dummy\template\home.html')`. Does it return true ?

Comment: Also, you should really replace     "D:/Data/Codes/Django_Code/dummy/template" by os.path.join() tricks, as mentionned in #1. I can see that in your config you use `/` but python always prints `\` so that might be a problem.

Comment: i have done following changes in settings.py                                            PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..')
STATIC_ROOT = 'os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'template')'

Comment: Did you fix TEMPLATE_DIRS too ? Did you try `os.path.exists` ?

Comment: what should be in TEMPLATE_DIRS ?

Answer (score 0):

Just copy and paste the template path in `setting.py`. It will solve this issue.

```
'DIRS': ['/Users/abc/dort/dort/templates'],
```

enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

On the browser where you get the error  ,  search 'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader'

There mentioned the path where django look for the template.

Example:

`django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: /code/templates/home.html (Source does not exist)`

Try to add your template in the same path above .

To avoid  the confusion add your template folder in the same directory as project_name and add `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')` in the [sqare bracket]  in front of DIRS  of settings.py

If your django site is hosted on docker , you need to see the exact path of template folder and need to mention it in settings.py

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the app name in the settings folder under the INSTALLED_APPS section